# php string generating by custom number

Tags: php, string, hash, numbers, generator

i found a code that i can make a random string generator with PHP:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

but i want to hash my `numeric ID` to hashed String

for example my Integer id is `118` so my hash must be `1a`

my `$chatresters` are 36 word and number, so every 36 multiple in my `ID` a new char in `hash`

```
ID  HASH
36  z
38  0b
107 0z
118 1a
```

Comment: Does your "numeric ID" fit into a php integer?

Comment: yes an Id = `int` @VolkerK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function base($int, array $digits) {
    $rv = ''; $int = (int)$int;
    while($int) {
        $rv = $digits[ $int%count($digits) ] . $rv;
        $int = (int)($int/count($digits)); // use %% for php7+
    }
    return $rv;
}

function base36($int) {
    static $digits = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
    return base($int, $digits);
}

foreach( array(35, 36,38,107,118) as $i ) {
    echo base36($i), "\r\n";
}
```

prints

```
10
12
2z
3a
```

a) it's not a hash; it's just another representation of the number using a base!=10
b) I think you forgot the zero in your examples ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hashids is a small open-source library that generates short, unique, non-sequential ids from numbers.

It should be able to meet your requirements.Official website:[http://hashids.org](http://hashids.org/)

An example:

```
<?php

$hashids = new Hashids\Hashids('this is my salt', 8, 'abcdefghij1234567890');

$id = $hashids->encode(1, 2, 3);
$numbers = $hashids->decode($id);

var_dump($id, $numbers);
string(5) "514cdi42"
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```